# Why this if statement is skipped all the time?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

My goal is to toggle class on element while document.scrollTop is over 300px

But somehow my statement is skipped all the time,can someone tell me why ?

```
if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 300)
            {

                $('.iconup').toggleClass('iconupscroll').removeClass('.iconup');


            }
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get in the console?

Comment: None,and that's the next confusing thing..Is else statement required or it can stay empty like else {} ?

Comment: It's not required to use else

Comment: create a fiddle example link. so that we can understand and help you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qxo53yhL/ Here's the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this  **[working fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/gd2u01vg/)**

```
$(function(){
$(document).scroll(function() {
 console.log( $(document).scrollTop())
  if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 300)
            {
            console.log(">300")
            //$('.iconup').toggleClass('iconupscroll').removeClass('.iconup');
            }
});
})
```

Check console log screenshot

[image]

Comment: It's Working :D Thank You very much mate :D But can you explain what was wrong ?

Comment: 1) Include Jquery
2) Add Js code inside $(function(){})
3) Add your scroll code inside $(document).scroll(); method

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `.scroll` event? Otherwise the if won`t be executed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 300)
            {
               $('.iconup').toggleClass('iconupscroll').removeClass('.iconup');
            }  
    })
});
```

Comment: jQuery is not included

Comment: Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/pva5mtue/ , the alert gets executet. You have another error there, because you have no `iconup` class....